# Auto Formatting statements in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, formatting

I am new to VS Code coming from Visual Studio 2017 and I really miss the auto-formatting options there. Like:

- Automatically format statement after I type a `;`
- Automatically format block when I type `}`
- Automatically format braces when they are automatically completed

My question is that is there any way to get these on options on VS Code, such as some tweaks on the `settings.json`?

Comment: Have you tried enabling format on type? `"editor.formatOnType": true`

Comment: Yes, I have its not working

Comment: Which language?

Comment: @MattBierner c++17

Answer (score 0):

I assume the C++ extension is enabled. To check if it is, go to the extensions tab on the left, and at the top click the three dot button and click "Show Built-in Extensions." That's where the C++ extension would be.

And I assume you've already checked this out, but there is some additional info here in the docs about including a .clang-format file and the fallback option if you don't.
[vscode-cpp-docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide)

In theory you should be able to format using the provided `"editor.formatOnType"` setting. If not, try installing the Clang-Format extension and see if that works. 
[Clang-Format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format)